# django-scheduler can't find static files

Tags: django, django-scheduler

I'm new to Django.  I followed the instructions on the README and then I couldn't find any further instructions on how to use scheduler, so I copied the fullcalendar.html from the django-scheduler-sample project into my project.  However, it can't find any of the css or js files required after a collectstatic or a bower install.  Is there a detailed tutorial somewhere on how to add django-scheduler to an app?  Why is fullcalendar.css not being added to staticfiles?  I'm using Django 1.10.5, Nginx, and Gunicorn.

Comment: what about js in sample project? https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler-sample/tree/master/project_sample

Comment: I didn't grab those because I thought the collectstatic would copy those over.  I can set up the sample project and the collectstatic does create all of the css/js files.  I can copy them from the sample project over, but that seems unintended.

Answer (score 5):

first u nead to install the django-scheduler with this command :

```
pip install django-scheduler
```

and add this to your setting.py on installed_apps:

```
'schedule',
```

second you need to install nodjs on your OS:

https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/

after this you need to set up your assets :

run this commands:

```
npm install -g bower
pip install django-bower
```

add this to settings.py

add to INSTALLED_APPS:

```
'djangobower',
```

Add staticfinder to STATICFILES_FINDERS:

```
'djangobower.finders.BowerFinder',
```

Specify the path to the components root (you need to use an absolute path):

```
BOWER_COMPONENTS_ROOT = '/PROJECT_ROOT/components/'
```

Add the following Bower dependencies for scheduler:

```
BOWER_INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'jquery',
    'jquery-ui',
    'bootstrap'
)
```

Last step, install bower dependencies with:

```
./manage.py bower install
```

and for more information read this :
https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler

http://django-scheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: I did all of those steps.  :)

Comment: If  you install the nodjs you should be fine. I think

Comment: I'm running npm 3.10.9. My process for this site was to create it using cookiecutter (https://github.com/pydanny/cookiecutter-django) and then follow the install instructions for django-scheduler.  So maybe having two jquery paths is what's causing problems, but I don't know why it wouldn't copy the fullcalendar stuff over with collectstatic.

Comment: Silly question but you running on virtual env?

Comment: Yes. Virtualenv with virtualenvwrapper and python 3.6

Comment: Ok. I reinstalled everything from scratch.  I only installed cookiecutter and then I installed django-scheduler.  I have no idea where to go from here.  collectstatic copied a bunch of images from schedule but no CSS or JS files.  bower install created a bunch of jquery stuff.  I can't get schedule to show up on my URLS.

Comment: when you u use external app on djano you must define the url on urls.py for using that.i dont familier with this app but in all of the instructure of apps ,when you install them it install the files on directory of your project in /env/.you should check that.how ever i tried to help you but im not expert that much.